# How to implement microdata attributes -- data-* and getting rid of the ID attribute?

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery 1.4.3.

I am trying to determine a best practice for using data-* attributes.  In the recent past, I have created checkboxes like this:

```
<input type='checkbox' id='123' class='Product' comp='1' man='1'>
<input type='checkbox' id='456' class='Product' comp='1' man='2'>
<input type='checkbox' id='789' class='Product' comp='2' man='3'>
```

The HTML 5 spec says that I shouldn't use custom attributes and that I should use data-* attributes.  Which means that the above checkboxes should really be like this:

```
<input type='checkbox' id='123' class='Product' data-comp='1' data-man='1'>
<input type='checkbox' id='456' class='Product' data-comp='1' data-man='2'>
<input type='checkbox' id='789' class='Product' data-comp='2' data-man='3'>
```

That's easy enough to accomplish, but with jQuery, I would usually call these elements by their id, which in this case happens to be the actual product id. So, my code to access these would be like this:

```
$(".Product").click(function() {
    var ProductID = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(ProductID );
});
```

Since the ID is really just a piece of data that I need to access, it should be a data-* attribute instead of an id.  I think what I really should be doing is this:

```
<input type='checkbox' class='Product' data-prodid='123' data-comp='1' data-man='1'>
<input type='checkbox' class='Product' data-prodid='456' data-comp='1' data-man='2'>
<input type='checkbox' class='Product' data-prodid='789' data-comp='2' data-man='3'>
```

This means that the id is no longer necessary for storing data, because I can do this:

```
$(".Product").click(function() {
    var ProductID = $(this).attr("data-prodid");
    alert(ProductID );
});
```

And if I want to check or uncheck a specific GROUP of boxes, I can do something like this:

```
// WHEN A PRODUCT IS CLICKED 
$(".Product").click(function() {
    // GET THE COMP
    var Comp = $(this).attr("data-comp");
    // UNCHECK BOXES WITH A DISSIMILAR COMP THAN THE ONE CLICKED
    $("[data-comp]!="+Comp).attr("checked", false);
});
```

It really seems like I can accomplish everything I need without using the id for storing data. Am I wrong? Is this how I should implement microdata storage? Is it correct that I will no longer need the id attribute except for CSS layout? Am I missing anything?

Comment: I'm a little bit confused but according to w3c spec any custom attribute should be prefixed with word 'data-' and in an input element like text box id, name and class attribute should be used normally without data, I think these are not counted as custom attributes. Other than these like 'comp' is a custom attribute and it should be used with a prefix 'data-'. A div or span can also have an id and class attributes. Correct me if I'm wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ID has its own meaning in HTML,CSS and Javascript.

- ID in HTML defines an unique element meaning it must be unique in a
  document.
- ID in CSS applies styling rules to a specific block or element.
- ID in JS will allow you to retrieve the element using
  document.getElementById.

You don't have any of those meaning when you use data attribute.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds reasonable.  The `id` must be unique across the whole DOM.  If those values are actually product identifiers, then use `data-prodid`.  You could have several DOM elements that represent the same product; duplicating the `data-prodid` attribute is perfectly legal.